# Postfix check_*_access class to simultaneously check sender AND recipient

Tags: email, postfix

We want to grant some specific servers of our network to send mails without authentication. I know that `check_sender_access` and `check_recipient_access` both can test sender (`MAIL FROM`) or recipient (`RCPT TO`).

To prevent heavy usage of `smtp_restriction_classes` I'm looking for a way to do such a lookup at once. I.e.

```
# /etc/postfix/check_noauth_servers
root@bi-server     jack@example.com
root@bi-server     jack@example.org
user@reporting     jack@example.org
```

Is there a solution or access restriction that can do such a lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking two unrelated questions.

The first,

> We want to grant some specific servers of our network to send mails
>   without authentification.

Is easily solved by placing a check_client_access in front of permit_sasl_authenticated:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/no-auth, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

and in `/etc/postfix/no-auth`:

```
your.server.name.or.ip    OK
```

- The second part of the question, however, seems to be talking about both sender and recipient access maps, at the same time.

This is precisely what `smtpd_restriction_classes` are for:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = noauth
noauth = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_recipients
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/allowed_senders, reject_unauth_destination
```

and in /etc/postfix/allowed_senders:

```
allowed_sender1@example.com  noauth
allowed_sender2@example.net  noauth
```

and in /etc/postfix/allowed_recipients:

```
allowed_recipient1@example.com  OK
allowed_recipient2@example.org  OK
```

In which order you apply the access checks is up to you.

If you need more complex rules (that combine senders and recipients in one check, for example) look into [**postfwd**](http://postfwd.org/), the Postfix FireWall Daemon.

This allows complex rules a la iptables, applied as a policy server (check_policy_service); the advantage of a policy service is that it has access to all pre-DATA parameters (client, helo , sender, recipient) at once.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly, what I have so for. But there are some of that servers, that need to be restricted, so that each server can use only its own sender address and is restricted in using recipients. So I have to use a dozen restriction classes and that's the point I want to optimize/minimize (whatever)

Comment: Ah, that is different. For simple sender-recipient pairing, look into `postfwd` - the postfix firewall daemon.

Comment: Yeah! Really great. As I see (and I think so) there is no way to do this in postfix directly without usage of dozens of classes. So `postfwd` is exactly what I'm looking for. Extend you answer, so I can accept it.